# dimmer switch only lights the first of 3 sets of lights

Tags: dimmer-switch

I recently changed out my incandescent lights in my kitchen to LED lights there are 3 lights each have 5 LED light bulbs with 2 3 way switches controlling their on/off function. I found the leg side and the power side, I was told to install the dimmer switch on the leg side but when I do that the dimmer switch only dims 1 of the 3 light fixtures> I'm trying to find out why and what can I do to correct this problem to control all of the lights connected to the switch

Comment: A diagram of the switch and light wires showing all hot, switched hot, traveler and neutral wires would help.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: Did it work before with incandescent lights?  What kind of LED did you use?  Also try putting 1 incandescent in each set of 5 and report back what happens....

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As said above, we'll need more info to be able to help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.